# Can I remount as readonly if there's a swap image in use?

Tags: linux, mount, swap, readonly

When am playing with my Android phone (CyanogenMod 10.1 with kernel 3.0.78), I found this:

- A script in `/etc/init.d/99system.swap.sh`
- It remount /system as rw, and creates an image file in `/system/swap/swap.img`

After the phone is started, I can find this swap.img file, and it is in use, by checking `/proc/swaps`. But the `/system` is mounted as ro.

I tried to do the same thing, by manual, on another phone. But when I try to remount `/system` as **ro**, I got error message saying there are resources in use. <strike>If I swapoff the image on `swap.img` file, I can immediately remount `/system` as **ro**.</strike>

I was wrong, I cannot remoutn `/system` as **ro** after I remount it as **rw**. *lsof* shows tons of process are using `/system`.

Comment: What kernel version are these phones running?

Comment: @Gilles it 3.0.78, from CM10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible in theory, as the `swapon` manpage states:

`[...] the swap file implementation in the kernel expecting to be able to write to the file directly, without the assistance of the file system [...]`

So when you have a swap file, the kernel likes to treat it more like a partition, i.e. it determines where the swap file is physically located on disk and then uses that region directly as it would with a partition region. This is a trick to make swapping to a file just as fast as to a regular partition.

At that point the filesystem is out of the loop and it should be okay to make the filesystem itself readonly. Whether you're actually allowed to do this is another matter; I haven't tested it myself and Android in particular may behave differently from regular Linux environment.

Comment: That's the general knowledge I learned about Linux, and since the `/system` is mounted as ro after that script, I guess Android should implemented the same way. But I just cannot remount it as ro...